# need to replace url href and tags

Tags: php, preg-replace

i need to replace a href using preg_replace with seo link , like

```
<a href="blabla" class="bla" style="bla">bla</a>
```

with

```
<a href="blabla.html" class="bla" style="bla">bla</a>
```

i need to get 2 vars first one to second one

i made this regex

```
preg_replace('#<a href="(.*?)" (.*?)>(.*?)</a>#',
             '<a href="$1.html">$3</a>'
               );
```

its work but if their is nothing after href="" tag like style or class the regex not work so the A must have style and class or somthing else to work

is their any way to ignore the class or style tag after href="" or any way to use this regext

```
preg_replace('#<a href="(.*?)"(>.*?)</a>#',
             '<a href="$1.html">$2</a>'
               );
```

or somthing like that to make it work as 1$ and 2$ only without 3$ ? i mean let the second one get every thing after `href"" to </a>` !

Comment: Why don't you ignore them in your regex, i.e, just match the `href` part.

Comment: Also you should go to your previous questions and accept the answers you find best.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just leave it as it is and use `mod_rewrite`?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Trying to parse HTML with regex may result in [the pony he comes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: my issue not with mod_write its with this regex only if someone help me to catch every thing after href="" to </a> i well be very much appreciated